# c# Десерилизация Json

Tags: c#, json, newtonsoft.json

Не могу понять как десерилизовать json

Код

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = @"{
  ""id"":""1"",
  ""email"":""mail@gmail.com"",
  ""vendor"":""demo"",
  ""default_forwarding_number"":""78009005040"",
  ""balance"":""100"",
  ""rating"":""96"",
  ""default_country"": {
    ""name"":""russia"",""iso"":""ru"",""prefix"":""+7""
  },
  ""default_operator"": {
    ""name"":""""
  },
  ""frozen_balance"":""0""
}";
        string responce = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data).ToString();
        var balance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<List<DefaultCountry>, List<DefaultOperator>>>>(responce);
        //var list = new Dictionary<string, List<RootBalance>>;
        //string s = balance[0].balance;
    }
    class _Balance
    {
        public string id { get; set; } = null;
        public string email { get; set; } = null;
        public string vendor { get; set; } = null;
        public string default_forwarding_number { get; set; } = null;
        public string balance { get; set; } = null;
        public string rating { get; set; } = null;
        public DefaultCountry default_country { get; set; } = null;
        public DefaultOperator default_operator { get; set; } = null;
        public string frozen_balance { get; set; } = null;
    }
    class DefaultCountry
    {
        public string name { get; set; } = null;
        public string iso { get; set; } = null;
        public string prefix { get; set; } = null;
    }

    class DefaultOperator
    {
        public string name { get; set; } = null;
    }

    class RootBalance
    {
        public string id { get; set; } = null;
        public string email { get; set; } = null;
        public string vendor { get; set; } = null;
        public string default_forwarding_number { get; set; } = null;
        public string balance { get; set; } = null;
        public string rating { get; set; } = null;
        public DefaultCountry default_country { get; set; } = null;
        public DefaultOperator default_operator { get; set; } = null;
        public string frozen_balance { get; set; } = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<_Balance>(data)`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, понял свою ошибку, в List или же коллекцию хотел добавить, то что и в целом не нужно было даже.

Comment: Смотрите всегда на структуру JSON, ей и следуйте. `{ ... }` - объект (обычно класс), `[ ... ]` - коллекция/массив, `"Name" : ...` - свойство с именем `Name` (если имя динамичное, то это будет уже словарь, где имя будет в ключе) и определенным типом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял, объяснили хорошо, до этого не сильно обращал что структура сильно влияет, в примере кода будь это коллекцией, это думаю работало бы. Но изменив также _Balance, на List<_Balance> перестает работать. Все из за структуры обычного класса или массивов значит)

Comment: `List<_Balance>` это тогда было бы в JSON такое: `[ { "Id" : "AAA", ...  }, { "Id" : "BBB", ...  }, { "Id" : "CCC", ...  } ]`, а у вас как видите один объект, не их коллекция.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это я уже понял) Так как коллекцию разными путями объявлял при десерилизации которые только знаю, а с вашего примера указав один объект-класс, сработало с первого раза)